# Bootstrap Multiselect: On submit getting length of selected options list instead of option values

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

This is my first time using [Bootstrap Muliselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect); it's been a completely elegant experience until this:

When my form is submitted, what comes through the POST request is the number of selected options from each `select.multiselect` element, not their values, ie:

If I create:

`<select name='foo'>`

with 3 options

```
<option value='b' selected='selected'>B</option>
<option value='a' selected='selected'>A</option>
<option value='r' selected='selected'>R</option>
```

subsequently typing `print_r($_POST)` produces:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => 3
)
```

I feel like this must be a facepalm sort of moment, but I've been at it for about two hours and though I can write ways to achieving this end, I can only assume Bootstrap is supposed to have such functionality by default. Anyone able to point me in the right direction, here?

Notes:

- For sure dependencies are installed & jQuery is loaded properly
- I'm using CakePHP & Foundation 4, but I don't think there are any conflicts/collisions
- I'm submitting the form via `$("#MahFormNaym").submit();` which I think doesn't matter but I am a JavaScript nub

**The PHP/HTML:**

```
<select id="<?php echo $model;?>-filter" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
<?php foreach($elements as $id => $element):?>
    <option value="<?php echo $id;?>"> <?php echo $element;?> </option>
<?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

**The JavaScript:**

```
$(".multiselect").multiselect({
    buttonWidth:"600px",
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    enableFiltering:true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't assigned your option a corresponding value to reflect `[foo] => 3`.  So, in order for this object to work like what you wanted, you need to assign the value with number like this:

```
<option value='0' selected='selected'>B</option>
<option value='1' selected='selected'>A</option>
<option value='2' selected='selected'>R</option>
```

Once node finds the specific number that matches to value, it'll then grab the content of the selected.

Comment: That was foolish and misleading error on my part; I do indeed have unique values for every option, the above was a typo, apologies [for those reading this later, where above my opt values are 'b' 'a' 'r' I had initially written 'b', 'b', 'b'].